Reduce LVM LVs Used for a BTrFS raid0 Array
Abstract
I have a BTrFS raid0 on top of multiple LVM LVs. Reducing the BTrFS devices works but the LVs fails as BTrFS reports entire array size instead of per-device allocated space, resulting in LVM refusing reduction with something like "Cannot reduce LV to 512GiB as it contains an FS of size 1TiB" (even though that is 1TiB spread across 2*512GiB BTrFS devices).
The raid layer is required to be on the BTrFS level as I need the option to also add another BTrFS RAID1 onto the same drives, which has to be on the BTrFS level to be able to express its hardware level redundancy (essence of raid1).
Setup
I have two disks. Each is configured as an LVM PV, defines its own VG consisting of only the one PV and a simple LV within. Those two LVs (one on each disk) are used to create a BTrFS raid0 array:
LVM
HDD0
  pv0
    vg0
      lv0
HDD1
  pv1
    vg1
      lv0

BTrFS
raid0
  devid 1 lv0
  devid 2 lv1

Each disk is 1TiB; LVs are set to 100%FREE, so each is 1TiB as well. The resulting BTrFS raid0 is 2TiB.
Problem
If I reduce the BTrFS filesystem on both devices to, let's say, 512GiB, my resulting FS is 1TiB. My (solid) assumption is that each device's block allocation is reduced to 512GiB.
However, attempting to reduce the underlying respective LV
lvreduce -L 512G vg0/lv0

results in the following LVM error:

File system btrfs found on vg0/lv0.
File system size (1.00 TiB) is larger than the requested size (512 GiB).
File system reduce is required and not supported (btrfs).

I.e. BTrFS reports the overall (raid0, sum of both devices) filesystem size when LVM asks for the size of one specific BTrFS device to reduce the underlying LV.
This clearly seems like BTrFS and LVM are completely talking past each other here. Is there a way around this issue or does it essentially render it impossible to reduce underlying LVs of a BTrFS raid0 (as long as >1 member is used in the array)? Many thanks in advance.

The usual practice is first to reduce the size of filesystem and then the LV/PV

And more important: what is the reason to have two VGs and RAID0 from BTrFS. Why not create RAID0 in LVM and then just a filesystem?

@RomeoNinov: The devel's in the detail here: I do reduce the BTrFS's FS size, but since this is a raid0 configuration, BTrFS reports the size of the entire array (which is twice the size of a single device for a two-device array). LVM refuses as LVM asks for the filesystem size on the single LV to not truncate it, but BTrFS reports the entire raid0 size.

@RomeoNinov: To answer your question: Moving the raid0 structure to the LVM layer and using a simple (zero or any redundancy really) BTrFS filesystem on a single LV that spans across the LVM raid0 does not allow for hardware-level BTrFS redundancy and with that resilience, which is a primary criterium.

You create RAID0, what is this redundancy you talk about?

@RomeoNinov: I didn't mention it initially to avoid unnecessary detail but it becomes relevant now that we're discussing the setup: The requirement is to ultimately have a (BTrFS) raid0 and raid1 alongside each other on the same drives, hence all the jazz about shoving LVM in between disks and BTrFS - I hope that clarifies the context.

You don't need to use LVM for BTRFS, in fact I don't even recommend to use LVM for BTRFS, it's like using LVM within LVM. BTRFS has an inbuilt LVM and supports multi device filesystems. You can add another device via btrfs device add /dev/sdXY /mnt/. What operating system do you use?

@paladin: This  is Linux. The specific niche is that I need both, a raid0 as well as a raid1 on the same set of hardware devices. As far as I'm aware BTrFS cannot run multiple profiles (explicitly) in the same filesystem, e.g. per-subvolue, hence the need to split the array up into two segments via LVM to be able to have two BTrFS fileystems (one raid0, one raid1) on top.

I strongly recommend not to use LVM for BTRFS. LVM is an old technology, even when widely used, it still has some "bugs", or let's call it "documented exceptional behavior", which can highly result in destruction of a BTRFS filesystem in case of malfunctions like sudden power off or hardware failures. If you really need 2 BTRFS filesystems, one "RAID0" and one "RAID1" then use ordinary GPT partitions. You don't need to allocate all of your device, if you don't want to. You can create as many future GPT partitions as you like and add these as devices to your BTRFS filesystems (raid0, raid1).

To be more precise, when using BTRFS on LVM, not the BTRFS filesystem is being destroyed in case of poweroff/hardware failure, but the LVM is going to become corrupt and BTRFS is able to detect this error (and when using just RAID0, BTRFS is not able to heal itself and thus becomes unwriteable, even RAID1 BTRFS might not help, in case the same LVM areas for both LV are corrupt). I've not much experience with ZFS filesystems but I think ZFS is able to create a filesystem as you would like. On the other hand ZFS is not as easy to configure as BTRFS.

@paladin: Thanks for the word of caution, it did feel a bit like digging up the past considering LVM but I saw no real alternative and wasn't aware of its specific shortcomings that you're hinting at. Unfortunately ZFS's redundancy profiles are directly coupled to the underlying hardware as well and can't directly be abstracted away, otherwise that would have been my go to for other scenarios. Scaling on the level of partitions is seems to be the only way, I'll try that out. If sizing of partitions is done right this should give flexibility to scale up and down as well. Many thanks.

Afterthought to my last comment: Scaling by means of many smaller partitions, as you suggest, would most likely come with a (pretty) negative performance hit (HDDs) and undermine BTrFS redundancy from what I read (no guarantee for copies on distinct devices for raid1, BTrFS might consider two partitions on the same drive the same way as two distinct drives but please correct if this is definitely not the case). Tricky one.

The negative performance hits are only relevant for absurd small partitions (sizes of less than 1GiB). To make sure such things don't happen, use partitions of at least 5GiB in size. In practice your partitions will be way bigger. BTRFS also supports online shrinking, so adjusting partition size is possible, even afterwards without much trouble. Just create 10 partitions, each 10% of total device capacity, this will give you enough flexibility. 20 partitions of 5% size would also be okay. Or just create partitions when needed.

You could create the first partition a 0% and the second partition at 50%. So you could also enlarge filesystems if needed, by enlarging the partitions, without the need of additional partitions. Maybe you can think about the needed size for each filesystem and adjust the starting positions.

Good points, I think this should work fairly well, particularly if performance overhead remains fairly limited. For raid0 I'm currently uncertain if BTrFS distributes chunks across all available devices (i.e. partitions) randomly or rather fills them up sequentially. Former should result in more seeks (many partitions on the same drive), latter should barely make a difference. Can you confirm by any chance? I'll use the first (and only first) partition on each drive for the raid1 and all others for raid0. Ability to add/remove & create new partitions at desired size should work well, nice.

Have you thought about using profile "single" instead of profile RAID0? RAID0 might increase IO speeds but also might have a bit more trouble when using different sized devices (example /dev/sda = 4TiB, /dev/sdb = 6TiB, /dev/sdc = 10 TiB). If increased IO speeds are not really important, I recommend using profile "single" instead of profile RAID0. Profile "single" is much more robust and safe to use than RAID0. Example: You lose one block device, with RAID0 your complete RAID is destroyed, with "single" you just need to repair the broken block device, which might save you some time.

PS In the event of an (unwanted) emergency, where a block device becomes corrupt, profile "single" allows to retrieve all files from the remaining block devices. You just lose the files from the broken device. You can even still mount the filesystem with read-only and copy files just as usual. RAID0 doesn't allow this mechanic, it just breaks. Maybe profile RAID10 could also work for you?

@paladin: I believe with BTrFS's RAID0 the available space would just be capped to the capacity of the smallest member in the array (for two drives). For three, let's say 4, 6, 8TiB, it would fill 4TiB of the first three and the remaining 2 of the second with 2 from the third, leaving 2 on the third unusable. I'm currently testing the approach you suggested above to scale both portions of the array (remember, I need a redundant and a non-redundant on the same set of disks) up or down, which might work quite well but RAID0 would perform terribly while SINGLE is a good fit for this setup.

I've split all devices into equally size partitions. The first of each is a RAID1 (not DUP to have guaranteed disk failure resilience, which DUP doesn't give), all other partitions are grouped into one big DUP profiled FS. A single RAID0 would have to go across all partitions on all drives, resulting in stripes across partitions of the me device, which would break performance. If BTrFS's RAID10 were strongly defined in its structure I could only create many RAID0s, each consisting of one partition on each drive, then group all those into one RAID1, which would break everything on a single

disk failure. Organizing orhogonally (RAID0 across partitions of one drive) would obviously be a no go for performance. Besides, I don't think BTrFS's RAID10 can be structured that explicitly, I believe it just organizes itself across the devices you give it. Current setup should work well: R/W performance like a single drive, capacity like RAID0 and, as you point out, only the specific disk's contents will need to be restored if one fails (or two etc.). Plus, flexibility in combination with the extra RAID1 on the same drives, probably w/out (considerable) performance impact; I'm testing...

As you've discovered, LVM can't work this out automatically, because it can't map from the LV structure it knows about to the btrfs device IDs it would need to be able to resize the right btrfs device.
You can do this manually, however. This involves overriding LVM's safety checks before resizing an LV, so make sure you understand what you're doing before you risk destroying your data!

Work out the btrfs device you need to resize. I'd normally do this with something like the below:
$ sudo btrfs device usage <mount-path>
/dev/dm-4, ID: 2
   Device size:             4.87TiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,RAID1:              1.60TiB
   Metadata,RAID1C3:        3.00GiB
   System,RAID1C3:         32.00MiB
   Unallocated:             3.27TiB

/dev/mapper/pi-av2, ID: 3
   Device size:             4.75TiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,RAID1:            189.00GiB
   Metadata,RAID1C3:        3.00GiB
   System,RAID1C3:         32.00MiB
   Unallocated:             4.56TiB

Note the output is inconsistent about whether it uses the /dev/dm-* form or the /dev/mapper/* form for the device path; you may want to run ls -l /dev/mapper/ to confirm which devices are which.  In any case, once you've worked out which device you want to resize, you need to note the ID number next to it.

Resize the btrfs device:
sudo btrfs filesystem resize <id>:<newsize> <mount-path>

<id> is the ID number you noted in the previous step.  <newsize> is the new size you want for the partition; you can also ask to shrink the partition by a specified amount, e.g. to shrink /dev/dm-4 by 4GB you'd use btrfs filesystem resize 2:-4G <mount-path>.

Run sudo btrfs device usage <mount-path> again, and confirm the "Device slack" line now has the amount of spare space you'd expect.

Resize the LV:
sudo lvresize --fs ignore -L <new-size> <lv>

Again, you can specify the size as an absolute size or a relative size, e.g. lvresize --fs ignore -L -4G pi/av1.
Do not shrink the LV by more than the amount of slack btrfs reported.  Normally lvresize would prevent you from doing this, but the --fs ignore argument tells it to skip that safety check.  Shrinking the LV so that it's smaller than the filesystem it contains is very likely to lose your data.



Thank you kindly me_and, this sounds like the solution I was looking for, I'll have to test this whenever I get a chance to get around do so. Spontaneous thought: It seems critical to make sure units are the same across APIs (decimal vs. binary in ambiguous G/GB (vs. GiB) notation)! Supposedly one could reduce the LV in smaller increments while keeping an eye on BTrFS's slack value for the device to make sure final amount of reduction is precise. Do you have experience in confirming integrity of resulting filesystem to make sure no data has gotten lost or corrupted?

When I've done this, it seems both BTRFS and LVM consistently interpret M and G as binary multiples, so you can use the same units with both, but reducing the LV incrementally while checking the slack reported by BTRFS is definitely the safer way to do this. I've never had any problems with data corruption, so I can't speak from experience, but I would expect btrfs scrub -B <mountpoint> would report integrity problems if there were any.

As per comments: because you use RAID0 via BTrFS you can't easy align the size of both LV's. You can't move the blocks because they are in different VGs. Not sure BTrFS  can give you the option for this also.
For me the best is to create backup of the files, then create RAID0 via LVM (one VG, one LV) and the create filesystem and restore the files.
As you mention you want to use some specific options from BTrFS so you can create this filesystem over two partitions (on HDD0 and HDD1, with partitions, resized on desired size) and then restore from backup.

Thanks for the thoughts, it's a little different though: The single devices of the BTrFS raid0 array can be resized to a specific target (see my original post, it should all be in there), so conceptually resizing LVs in this configuration is possible and straight forward. One relevant detail I only imply above: I do need BTrFS level redundancy (e.g. another BTrFS raid1 over a set of separate LVs, which I can only get through BTrFS raid1 (anything else would result in something effectively equivalent to DUP (vs. raid1)).

@bossi, just create RAID1 (or RAID10) in LVM (or via metadevices) and put the filesystem. IMHO you overcomplicate the things, use volume management for RAID, filesystem for filesystem

I've considered that but having raid1 in LVM instead doesn't give me BTrFS level redundancy. I.e. BTrFS wouldn't be able to provide its resilience as it's not managing redundancy. So, for instance, raid1 on LVM, BTrFS (single, dup, raid1.. whatever) on top. One disk fails - BTrFS would have no way to heal itself as redundancy is on the LVM layer and LVM doesn't have hashed data resilience as BTrFS does to heal itself, if I'm not mistaken - i.e. all of BTrFS's disk-level redundancy would break away.
